# Pgfplotstable ignores chars in filename

Tags: tables, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am using the `ignore chars` key from the `pgfplotstable` to ignore some characters in a table.

However, I have noticed that it also removes characters from the file name and I am wondering if this is a bug.

Here is an example where the ignored char is `s`. The result is that the table `height.dat` instead of `heights.dat` is printed.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{filecontents}{heights.dat}
height
1
5
8
11
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{height.dat}
height
0
0
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[ignore chars={s}]{heights.dat}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify the format of the input. In your case it's a file:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[ignore chars={s},format=file]{heights.dat}
```

The option is also explained at [page 8 of the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplotstable.pdf)

Comment: Good catch! Seems as if it is the auto-detection if the argument is a file or an inline-table which causes the misbehavior (which is probably still a bug).